# Проверка: сколько раз запущена программа

Tags: c#

Вот скажите, я хочу сделать так, что если первый раз программа запущена, то картинка image1 показывается, а если программа уже запускалась на этом компьютере, то image2. И пробовал использовать Параметры, но не получается, есть ошибка:

> Ошибка 1 Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "object" в "bool". Существует явное преобразование (возможно, пропущено приведение типов) `D:\dima\Новый год\Новый год\Form1.cs`  33  16  Новый год

Кто знает, как проверять, запускалась программа на компьютере или нет?

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/articles/singleinstance.php Попробуйте прочесть статью. Там наглядно рассказано как определить, что программа уже запущена.

Answer (score 2):

Надо сохранять данные о запуске где-нибудь, например, в реестре или в настройках. В [настройках](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a65txexh(v=VS.100).aspx) - проще всего. Во время запуска

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.IsAlreadyUsed != true) {
    Properties.Settings.Default.IsAlreadyUsed = true;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Настройку надо добавить в свойствах проекта в студии.

Comment: http://s017.radikal.ru/i408/1111/4c/d14b754e8338.jpg вот какая ошибка

Answer (score 1):

```
Mutex a = new Mutex (false, "yourProgramName", out isFirst);
if (isFirest){}else{}
```

Примерно так.

Comment: А что за Mutex?

Comment: ну если интересно, то http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81

Answer (score 1):

Вам же компилятор написал: возможно, пропущено приведение типов. Проблема не в том, что что-то с параметрами, а в том, что Вы пишете что-то недопустимое с точки зрения синтаксиса C#.